# looping over 3d matrix and printing values

Tags: python, multidimensional-array

I am trying to loop over a 3d matrix and access the values and get some count values for finding probability. I am successful in it but one thing is i am assuming b=0 initially which i dont want to since it gives a small error in my probability which i want to reduce. the matrix is

```
 array([[[  1,   1,   1,   1, -99, -99],
    [  1,   1,   1,   1, -99, -99],
    [  1,   1,   1,   1, -99, -99],
    [  1,   1,   1,   1,   1, -99]],

   [[-99, -99, -99, -99, -99, -99],
    [-99, -99, -99, -99, -99, -99],
    [-99, -99, -99, -99, -99,   1],
    [-99, -99, -99, -99, -99,   1]],

   [[  1,   1,   1,   1,   1,   1],
    [  1,   1,   1,   1,   1,   1],
    [  1,   1,   1,   1,   1,   1],
    [  1,   1,   1,   1,   1,   1]],

   [[  1,   1,   1,   1,   1,   1],
    [  1,   1,   1,   1,   1,   1],
    [  1,   1,   1,   1,   1,   1],
    [  1,   1,   1,   1,   1,   1]]], dtype=int16)
```

and the code i ran is:

```
 for i in range(4):
...     for j in range(6):
...         b=NR=NN=RR=RN=0
...         for k in range(4):
...             a = array[k][i][j]
...             if(a==0 and b==0):
...                 NN+=1
...                 b=a
...             elif(a==0 and b==1):
...                 RN+=1
...                 b=a
...             elif(a==1 and b==0):
...                 NR+=1
...                 b=a
...             elif(a==1 and b==1):
...                 RR+=1
...                 b=a
...             else:
...                 exit
...         print(NN,NR,RN,RR)
```

for this i get extra 24 'NR' values which i dont want to occur by not initializing b. When i did not initialize b i got the following output:

```
(0, 0, 0, 3)
(0, 0, 0, 3)
(0, 0, 0, 3)
(0, 0, 0, 3)
(0, 0, 0, 2)
(0, 0, 0, 2)
(0, 0, 0, 3)
(0, 0, 0, 3)
(0, 0, 0, 3)
(0, 0, 0, 3)
(0, 0, 0, 2)
(0, 0, 0, 2)
(0, 0, 0, 3)
(0, 0, 0, 3)
(0, 0, 0, 3)
(0, 0, 0, 3)
(0, 0, 0, 2)
(0, 0, 0, 3)
(0, 0, 0, 3)
(0, 0, 0, 3)
(0, 0, 0, 3)
(0, 0, 0, 3)
(0, 0, 0, 3)
(0, 0, 0, 3)
```

which is not correct because the actual output is

```
(0, 1, 0, 2)
(0, 1, 0, 2)
(0, 1, 0, 2)
(0, 1, 0, 2)
(0, 1, 0, 1)
(0, 1, 0, 1)
(0, 1, 0, 2)
(0, 1, 0, 2)
(0, 1, 0, 2)
(0, 1, 0, 2)
(0, 1, 0, 1)
(0, 1, 0, 1)
(0, 1, 0, 2)
(0, 1, 0, 2)
(0, 1, 0, 2)
(0, 1, 0, 2)
(0, 1, 0, 1)
(0, 1, 0, 2)
(0, 1, 0, 2)
(0, 1, 0, 2)
(0, 1, 0, 2)
(0, 1, 0, 2)
(0, 1, 0, 2)
(0, 1, 0, 2)
```

without the value '1' in the second column. Any suggestions on how i can solve this?

Comment: On first iteration where a = array[0][0][0] what should b be ?

Comment: that is also part of problem here. when i initialize b=0 i can understand the program but when i dont initialize b, what value does it take and runs is still a mystery to me. But during first iteration i want a=array[1][0][0] and b=[0][0][0] so and then b=a for my code.

Comment: So why is RR = 2 or does that count when a = array[0][0][0]  and b = array[4][0][0]

Comment: well i have printed values for each cell seperately. as u can see my innermost loop is 'k' so i loop over a single m*n cell over all 4 layers and after fourth layer i print the values. and no array[0][0][0] and array[3][0][0] wont be compared since ive given b=a after looping. and RR value as whole will be summation of all RR values of 24 cells.

Comment: Consider the first iteration when I=j=0, 1st a = -99 b = 1 RR=0, 2nd a = 1 b = -99 RR=0, 3rd a = 1 b = 1  RR=1. RR is now printed, why is it 2 ?

Comment: as you can see i have initialized b as 0 for the second output displayed. so for first iteratoin b is 0 and then b=a as per the loop. But when i dont initialize i have no idea what b is taken as for first loop and so i have posted the output asking what have went wrong there. and RR value is 2 because only when a!=-99, b=a will be executed else the loop just moves on with next 2d matrix.

Comment: Ok I missed the 'exit' - should that not be break if you want to move on to the next j

Comment: sorry i dont get you?... if u can see the code correctly i think it'll be clear to you when which loop stops and runs. only when k=3, the loop moves i and when all i has completed for current 'j' it moves to next j loop. here i-row, j-column and k-layers.

Comment: What I don't understand is why you have a 'exit' command in else ? Should it be continue, or maybe you don't need an else statement at all.

Comment: i have an exit because i dont just have 0's and 1's but also -99 which i dont want to take into consideration. if a=-99 the exit statement ensures if loop is finished and a takes value from next 2d matrix.

Answer (score 0):

To skip a loop iteration use [continue](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_for_loops.asp) not exit (which is not a valid command). Since on the first iteration there is no valid b value, initialize it to -99. Skip summation and the b=a assignment if a=-99 so that b retains the last valid a value.

```py
for i in range(4):
     for j in range(6):
         NR=NN=RR=RN=0
         b = -99
         for k in range(4):
            a = array[k][i][j]
            if a == -99 : continue
            if(a == 0 and b == 0): NN+=1
            elif(a == 0 and b == 1): RN+=1
            elif(a == 1 and b == 0): NR+=1
            elif(a == 1 and b == 1): RR+=1  
            b=a
         print(NN,NR,RN,RR)
```